# javafx 1.3 jnlp not working

Tags: java, javafx, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a javafx 1.3 application that it is running perfectly with "javafx -jar myjar.jar" but I need to distribute it and I'm building the jnlp corresponding file. The problem is that each time that I run it I have the following error:

```
Java Web Start 1.6.0_31
Using JRE version 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3635 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = /Users/ana
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging 
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/runtime/eula/Eula
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:345)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.swing.SwingToolkit$StartupRoutine.run(SwingToolkit.fx:855)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at        java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:652)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.runtime.eula.Eula
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:345)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 30 more
```

If I uncompress the jar file, I can see the class Eula.class in the path com/sun/javafx/runtime/eula so I don't know if I have to specify in some way that it should look on the jar file.

My jnlp file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:/Users/ana/Projects/" href="MatchTestCaseGenerator.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>Match Test Case Generator</title>
    <vendor>Knowledge Values</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
    <description>somc description</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
    <shortcut>
        <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
</information>
<security>
     <all-permissions/>
</security>
<update check="background" policy="always"/>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
    <jar href="MatchTestCaseGenerator-2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
    <extension href="http://dl.javafx.com/1.3/javafx-rt.jnlp" name="JavaFX Runtime"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="com.sun.javafx.runtime.main.Main" progress-class="com.javafx.progressbar.ProgressManager">
    <argument>MainJavaFXScript=com.knowledgevalues.mtcg.javafx.MainFx</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: I finally got it. The problem is having javafx .class inside the jar file. The only .class that it should be inside the jar is the Main one. :)